# Puppet: Can the puppetdb run on the same server as the puppet master?

Tags: linux, automation, puppet, open-source

My Question ist if the puppetdb can run on the same server as the puppet master?
Is this easily possible, or is there a reason why the documentation says it should run on different servers (other than performance)

Version of server and DB : 7

https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/7/install_via_module

Answer (score 1):

> My Question ist if the puppetdb can run on the same server as the puppet master?

Yes.

> Is this easily possible,

Yes.

> or is there a reason why the documentation says it should run on different servers (other than performance)

I'm uncertain to what part of the Puppet documentation you're referring.  However, in the middle of the page you've linked in your question, you can find:

> If you are installing PuppetDB on the same server as your Puppet Server [...]

At least that page anticipates that that is something you might do, then.  There are capacity / performance reasons why you might want to put PuppetDB on its own machine, but Puppet has never required that.